# Is there an Oracle proxy connection available in PHP?

Tags: java, php, oracle

We are converting an existing Java application to PHP.  Inside the Java code, the developer connects to a database as one user, then uses a Java call to the function

```
((OracleConnection)conn).openProxySession(OracleConnection.PROXYTYPE_USER_NAME, props);
```

which appears to open a proxy session inside the database as another user.  My understanding of Java is incomplete but I believe this is what it is doing.  Is there a function in PHP which will allow us to accomplish the same goal?

TIA,
Mike

Comment: PHP has many ways to connect to databases, the best being the PDO connection.

Comment: If you are using OCI to connect via php I would say no

Comment: May be DRCP helps http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/php-scalability-ha-twp-128842.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [Oracle OCI manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/LNOCI/oci-programming-basics.htm#GUID-D77D0D4A-7483-423A-9767-CBB5854A15CC), since PHP Oracle extensions are implemented in OCI.

`SQL> alter user user2 grant connect through user1;`

You can test it with SQL*Plus, which is also written in OCI:

`sqlplus -l user2[user1]/user2pw@localhost/pdborcl
...
SQL> show user
USER is "USER1"`

So in PHP OCI8 use:

`$c = oci_connect('user2[user1]', 'user2pw', 'localhost/pdborcl');`

There was a user comment recommending PDO.  The PHP OCI8 extension has more features and is able to take advantage of more Oracle features (statement caching, DRCP etc) so there is a strong recommendation to use OCI8.

Comment: Thanks, @Christopher, for your clear and concise answer.  We have been using OCI8 with great success in our shop and I will second your recommendation for that extension.  I unfortunately do not have alter user rights on our database in question so have to wait for our DBA to get some time so I can tinker around with your solution.  It certainly shows promise.  I will update when I have tested it.

Comment: This works!  Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge!